# Deallocate [deallocate]!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [deallocate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deallocate) tag is useless! The tag wiki and and tag excerpt simply says:

> refer to memory-deallocation

<sup>How is this a useful  tag at all?!</sup>

As [memory-deallocate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-deallocate) already exists and is a well-defined tag, I suggest we burninate [deallocate] and deallocate the data involved. Let's retag these questions to [memory-deallocate] (synonym of [memory-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-management)) instead!

Some convincing stats for you:

- 57 questions (Not much at all);
- No [deallocate] experts (And no user even has over 5 answers or over 10 total score of the tag.)
- 22.8% remains unanswered; Though no activity within last 30 days.

Notes:

- This tag is most used with [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointers) to refer to [memory-deallocation]; However only 15 questions are involved, a manual retag will be sufficient.
- This tag is often misused with "memory" to refer to [memory-deallocation]. Again, we need a retag for this.

Comment: So? Just do it already.

Comment: @Deduplicator Will do if there are no objection in a few days. Burninating another tag ATM. :)

Comment: Someone's bored

Comment: I'm going to go through and retag a handful of posts...

Comment: Why is this a burninate request rather than a retag request?

Comment: The tag is useless, we should get rid of it and salvage (retag) the questions that could actually use one - as it's often misused, a burnination is more effective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Retagging Done**

[deallocate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deallocate) has been deallocated from all existing questions.  Almost everything was retagged with [memory-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-management).  I also picked up a few instances of [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delete), [release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/release) and [destroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/destroy).

There were a few uses for SQL that were not related to memory management.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for taking the action to remedy this.