# Should I raise a flag to request a completed burninate request be tagged [status-completed]?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, meta, burninate-system

I noticed a good amount of [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) here on meta which have been completed, but have not been marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). I went to 7 of these posts today, and after verifying that their tags have indeed been burned, I raised a custom moderator flag with the following formats:

> Please tag [status-complete]. The [x] tag has been burned.
>
> Please tag this burninate request as [status-complete]. The [x] tag has been burned.

<sub>I made the second format because I thought the first was not verbose enough. Also just realised that it's "completed" not "complete".</sub>

However, I am having second thoughts about doing this. I consulted with rene and [he said](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/20079015#20079015) that I may be wasting the moderator's time, though linked me ["When editing on Meta are flags requesting 'status-something' considered useful?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103485). The post says that these tags *are* helpful, but does not explicitly say for burnination requests.

I haven't had any of these flags declined so far, though only 2 have been approved. The rest from today are still in the queue.

My main question can be broken into two sections:

1. Should burnination requests be tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) when the tag has been burned?
2. Should I be raising a custom moderator flag to request adding the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag?

<sub>If someone would like an example, I flagged [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268373/deallocate-deallocate), which a moderator deemed helpful and added the tag</sub>

Comment: `[status-completed]`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

At least, that's what I do. I don't see any problem with tagging [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) something that is completed and doesn't need further iterations. Also, this is how the tag is supposed to be used:

> A feature request has been implemented, a bug has been fixed, or a **request has been processed.**

Comment: Yes, this is fine. Moderators are not on top of the Meta flag queue as much as the one on the main site, so it might take us a while to notice the flag, but it's really no bother to take care of stuff like this. Only mods and SE employees can add this tag, and it only takes a moment. Flag away.

Comment: Thanks for the moderator confirmation Bill.