# Should I stop raising custom mod flags to retag to one of the [status-*] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, flags

When a question has its request completed, I often raise a custom moderator flag to request retagging of the question to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). It's the same story for [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)-type questions.

I've been doing this for quite a while:

[image]

[image]

[image]

http://puu.sh/kFxdW/85b4ffc072.png

[image]

[image]

[I asked in the SOCVR Chat this:](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/26212963#26212963)

> am I the only one who raises custom mod flags to request retag to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) once the request in the question has been completed?

[Tiny Giant replied with:](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/26213001#26213001)

> Yes.

I know that one user hardly represents the whole site, but how common is this behaviour? Is it taboo?

Should I stop raising the custom mod flags to request the moderator-only retag?

I'm fully aware that I may be wasting the valuable time of the moderators here, hence me asking this question. I realise that almost all my flags of this type (retag to a [tag:status-*] tag) have been marked `helpful`, but I can't help thinking that requesting retags in this fashion are becoming repetitive.

Comment: Have a look at [Bill's comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277597/should-i-raise-a-flag-to-request-a-completed-burninate-request-be-tagged-status#comment120674_277608) on this [answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277608/4099593). I guess it answers your problem :-)

Comment: @BhargavRao Cheers- I dupehammered as a duplicate of that question.